# HttpUtility.JavaSciptStringEncode decoding

Tags: c#, .net, string, odata

I have a long string which have to be passed to wcf web method. This string starts with

```
\b\0\0\0\0\0\0.....
```

and has a lot of unprintable symbols. I've tried to HttpUtility.HtmlEncode this string, but it doesn't work. The only way to pass needed string to server is to use HttpUtility.JavaSciptStringEncode method.

But on the server side I have no idea how to decode this string to previous state. HttpUtility.UrlDecode doesn't help.

How to properly decode string on the server side?

Thanks

Comment: how about `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`?

Comment: HttpUtility.HtmlDecode is not a solution. I found a resolution: I had to Base64 encode string before HttpUtility.UrlEncode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. I had to `Base64` encode string before use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`. `HttpUtility.JavaSciptStringEncode` is not needed now.